# HighChart Time Series hours starting at 4pm

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I have a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sawaira/944zsyy5/2/

```
$(function () {
console.log( [new Date(2010, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 1],
                [new Date(2010, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 2],
                [new Date(2010, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0), 3],
                [new Date(2010, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0), 4]);
    Highcharts.setOptions({                                            // This is for all plots, change Date axis to local timezone
                global : {
                    useUTC : false
                }
            });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        // Show hour and am/pm
                        console.log(this.value);
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat("%l %p", this.value);
                    },                    
                },           
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                 [new Date(2010, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 1],
                [new Date(2010, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 2],
                [new Date(2010, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0), 3],
                [new Date(2010, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0), 4]               
             ]
        }]

    });
});
```

When using the HighChart options to render times on the X-axis, I am always getting results starting at 4pm. Please note, `useUTC` is false and I have added bunch of `console.log()` to see if the time values are as expected and they are.

Why am I getting the result I describe above?

Comment: It appears that changing the value to .getTime() makes it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that changing the value to .getTime() makes it work.

Comment: If that's the solution, then please mark it as accepted answer. If not - using `Date.UTC()` instead of `new Date()` seems to resolve the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/944zsyy5/4/